# passing content of variables within command line submitted to bsub

Tags: bash, unix

If I execute the following:

```
var1=`echo King`;  var2='David';bsub -q big "echo 'Hello' $var1 $var2 > Output.txt;"
```

this bsub submission works just fine and the resultant Output.txt file is:

```
Hello King David
```

Thus, bsub knows how to use variables that were assigned outside of bsub.

For the sake of learning, I'd like to know how I may create new variables within the bsub command and pass the content of variables generated outside to variables generated INSIDE bsub.

For example:

```
var1=`echo King`;  var2='David';bsub -q big "echo 'Hello' $var1 $var2 > Output.txt; var3=$var2; var4=`echo Queen`; var5='BOYS'; echo $var3 $var4 $var5>> Output.txt"
```

so the desired output would be:

```
Hello King David
David Queen BOYS
```

*the idea here is basically to learn how to submit a composed command line to bsub (and by doing so to escape the need of creating a .bash file that would hold all commands submitted to bsub).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
answer is this:

```
var1=`echo King`;  var2='David';bsub -q big "echo 'Hello' $var1 $var2 > Output.txt; var3=$var2; var4=`echo Queen`;var5='BOYS'; echo \$var3 \$var4 \$var5>> Output.txt"
```

Output.txt is

```
Hello King David
David Queen BOYS
```